# VBA what datatype is a dialogsheet?

Tags: vba

I can't find DialogSheets in the object browser in VBA. Dim dialog as ??? I like to see the autocomplete so I can know all the properties and methods of a particular type. VarType tells me it is just an object but is there a better or more specific way of finding out the type of an object? For example the OptionsButtons method... how am I supposed to know this thing even exists when it is not in the object browser?

Comment: *(necropost)* My guess is that you can view them in the object browser if you add a reference to the old VBA library (which you would have to search online and download) from the time that these weren't obsolete. Edit: though I'm not sure how to reference a library with the name conflicting with the built-in VBA library that comes with Excel and that you can't remove from references. So maybe only using an older version of Excel.

Comment: @user7393973 nice guess only took you 4 years

Comment: I only found the question today so yeah, also [here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58858438) to browse the hidden objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find them in the object browser because they are obsolete. They are just available for copatibility reasons.

You should use `UserForms` instead. In your vba editor click *Insert*, *UserForm*. Now you can easily create a userform with drag and drop.

Have a look here for more about dialog sheet: [What exactly is a "dialog sheet" in Excel](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/what-exactly-is-a-dialog-sheet-in-excel/9d35a5a2-a40d-41a8-819f-715d3c546da2)

Comment: Even though they are obsolete the VBA editor still recognizes the secret methods hidden in the classes. Where can I see a list of these properties/methods?