# How to reference an old version of the VBA library?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013. The VBA reference is part of Excel ([built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.reference.builtin)) so I can't remove it.

Is it possible to reference another version of the VBA library? The reason I want to know other than curiosity is to look at the object browser of the older versions to see if it lists some currently-hidden/obsolete properties/methods such as [Excel.DialogSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134174/vba-what-datatype-is-a-dialogsheet).

The [Workbook.SheetActivate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetactivate) has a `Sh` parameter of type Object. One of the possible sheet types is [`Excel.DialogSheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.dialogsheet) which [should be checked with the TypeOf operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42442824).

When I try to add another VBA reference I get the message: `Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library`.

The default one being used is from:

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL

The other references available are from:

- C:\Windows\System32\msvbvm60.dll
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\VEN2232.OLB

I also checked another computer with Excel 2003 that uses:

- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6.DLL

And has:

- C:\WINDOWS\system32\VEN2232.OLB
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVBM50.DLL
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVBM60.DLL
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\VBAEND32.OLB

Comment: Interesting question (which you get 10 reps points for as of yesterday). Pragmatic solution: find a friend with an old, unused machine languishing in their basement? I would imagine that it would be serious DLL hell to get all the dependencies right on your current machine.

Comment: @JohnColeman I had noticed the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) but hadn't read it whole, that's nice. The solution below is ideal for me, I wouldn't want to mess with editing DLLs. Though if someone does know a way to still reference it (preferably a pratical solution) then I will still upvote the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is no. Also, there is no need to. Just open the Object Browser, right-click something and choose 'Show hidden members'. You can then browse all the deprecated features like `DialogSheet` to your heart's content. :)

Comment: I had no idea about that [option](https://i.imgur.com/boekl4B.png). Thanks :)